# JSS returns 404 for media items in Richtext

Tags: jss, richtext-editor, mediaurls

I have a Legacy hybrid solution on SC 9.2 where only some page types are migrated to JSS.

The issue is that if I insert an Internal Sitecore Link to a media item, it returns 404.

Internal link works and the markup looks ok (in both legacy and JSS):

```
<a href="/relative-path-of-the-page">Test page</a>
```

But media items (imgs and pdf files) return 404 and the markup looks like below (in both legacy and JSS):

```
<a href="media_library_prefix/~/media/d494d2a8a8554dbf977695dbdd4e94b5.ashx">
```

---

The request for URL for media, in Legacy solution:

```
Request URL: http://myDomain/parentItem_path/media_library_prefix/~/media/d494d2a8a8554dbf977695dbdd4e94b5.ashx
```

and in JSS:

```
Request URL: http://myDomain/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?sc_apikey={api_guid}&item=/parentItem_path/media_library_prefix/~/media/d494d2a8a8554dbf977695dbdd4e94b5.ashx&sc_lang=en
```

Any advices on what can I do to make Richtext to return the proper working URL ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using JSS 18? There is a fix for media library urls - https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Headless%20Rendering/18x/Sitecore%20Headless%20Rendering%201800/Release%20Notes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that JSS needs the media library link to start with forward slash:

```
<a href="/media_library_prefix/~/media/d494d2a8a8554dbf977695dbdd4e94b5.ashx">
```